Build a BBox with a NE and SW corner from two locations with lat,lngs in Kotlin?
I have two points defined like this:
data class Location(val lat: Double, val lng: Double)

and a bbox class defined like this:
data class Bbox (val neCorner: Location, swCorner: Location)

The problem I'm having is ensuring that the points are in the right place. So given a function like this, it seems like I need to handle points being across the anti-meridian, and can't just say something like "coordinate1" is always NE and "coordinate2" is always SW.
What is the proper logic for this, where given two points, their coordinates are placed properly in the bbox?
fun getBbox(coordinate1: Location, coordinate2: Location): Bbox {

}


This is a rather broad subject. Anti-meridian crossing is more complex than it appears at first sight. If you are using only Kotlin JVM, maybe you can use a library for this, ike Apache SIS. Its documentation provides some insights regarding this problem. You can look at GeneralEnvelope#normalize apidoc and SIS developer guide.
